# Python - My query to extract prime numbers does not work

Tags: python

I am attending a course on Udemy and one of the exercises is to return all the prime numbers from a range of numbers (for example all prime numbers before 100)

**This is the query that the teacher made**

```
def count_primes2(num):
    
    #Check for 1 or 0
    if num < 2:
        return 0
    ######################
    #2 or greater
    #Store our prime numbers
    primes = [2] #I start my list with 2 that is a prime number
    #Counter going up to the input num
    x = 3 #I create a variable on which I will continue adding until I reach num
    # x is going through every number up to the input num
    while x <= num:
        #Check if x is prime
        for y in range(3,x,2):  # for y in range from 3 to x in even steps, we only wantto check odd numbers there
            if x%y == 0:
                x += 2 
                break
        else:
            primes.append(x)
            x += 2
    print(primes)
    return len(primes)
count_primes2(100)
```

However, I came up with the one below that is not working. My idea is:

Given each number i between between 3 and num+1 (for example 100 would be 101 so that 100 can be included in the calculation):

- Open a **for loop** in which I divide i by each number g before i (including i) and I have a counter checking when this division gives no remainder. This implies that in case of prime numbers the counter should always be 2 (for example 3--> 3:1 and 3:3 would give remainder 0).
- If the counter is equal to 2, then i is a prime and I want to append it to the list.

I am not using any while loop in my query. Can you help me to identify why my query is not working?

```
def count_prime(num):
    counter=0
    list_prime=[2]
    if num<2:
        return 0
    for i in range(3,num+1):
        for g in range(1,i+1):
            if i%g==0:
                counter+=1
        if counter==2:
            list_prime.append(i)
    
    return list_prime
count_prime(100)
```

Comment: "not working"—give more detail

Comment: The first query correctly returns all the prime numbers while my query returns [2]

Comment: You need to set `counter` back to zero for each new `i` you are checking.

Comment: Thanks!
def count_prime(num):
    counter=0
    list_prime=[2]
    if num<2:
        return 0
    for i in range(3,num+1):
        for g in range(1,i+1):
            if i%g==0:
                counter+=1
        if counter==2:
            list_prime.append(i)
        counter=0
    
    return list_prime
count_prime(100)

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to **Khelwood** for the help. Below the working query:

```
def count_prime(num):
    counter=0
    list_prime=[2]
    if num<2:
        return 0
    for i in range(3,num+1):
        for g in range(1,i+1):
            if i%g==0:
                counter+=1
        if counter==2:
            list_prime.append(i)
        counter=0
    
    return list_prime
count_prime(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may do this :

```
for i in range(2,num):
if (num % i) == 0:`
```

Instead of using two for loops, you can simply eliminate one of the for loop and do this, I hope this may work for you.
thankyou.

Comment: While you offered another solution TS asked for help why his/her solution does not work. Please pay attention to questions and provide appropriate answer.